# Ошибка вызова свойства или метода

Tags: actionscript

Здравствуйте! Написал код для викторины. Всё работает, вопросы задаются рандомно, но в определённый момент приложение останавливается и выводится следующая ошибка: "TypeError: Error #1009: Не удается вызвать свойство или метод со ссылкой на объект "null".at Main/asking() at Main/onClick()". Пробовал её устранить, применял трассировку, но не обнаружил баг. Ко всему прочему, ошибка возникает каждый раз в новом месте: она может появиться как после первого вопроса, так и после десятого или любого другого. Бьюсь уже второй день, не нашёл ответ в поисковике. Вот сам код:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.*;
import TfFormat;

public class Main extends Sprite {
    var externalXML:XML;//загруженный XML
    var numOfQuestion:Number;//число вопросов
    var currentXML:XML=new XML;//XML текущего вопрсоа
    var currentElementText:String='';//текущий вариант ответа
    var i;// номер текущего вопроса
    var massiv:Array=[];// массив с ответами
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest("super.xml");
    var textF:TfFormat = new TfFormat;
    var rnd:RND; //экземпляр генератора номера вопроса

    public function Main() {

        loader.load(request);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, preOnComplete);
    }       
    /*
    Функция загрузки XML-файла
    */
    function preOnComplete(event:Event):void {
        var tf:TextField = new TextField;
        tf.text = 'Викторина'
        tf.setTextFormat(textF);
        var goStart:AnswerBut = new AnswerBut('запуск викторины');
        tf.x =30;
        tf.y =30;
        tf.width = 300;
        tf.height = 40;         
        goStart.x = 50;
        goStart.y = 50;
        addChild(tf);
        addChild(goStart);
        goStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onComplete);
    }

    function onComplete(event:Event):void {
        if (this.numChildren>1) {
            while (this.numChildren > 1) {
                this.removeChildAt(1);
            }
        }
        if (loader!=null) {
            externalXML=new XML(loader.data);                                   
            numOfQuestion = externalXML.quest.length();

            asking(externalXML.quest.length()+1); //запускаем первый вопрос

        }
    }
```

/
*Функция asking(numOff) отвечает за процесс задачи конкретного вопроса. В параметр функции 
передается номер предыдущего вопроса, который не должен задаваться повторно. При
первом запуске функции этот номер больше длины массива вопросов.*
/

```
    function asking(numOff):void {
            var currentRandom:Number = numOff;  //присваиваем текущему номеру
                                                //вопроса предыдущий номер вопроса
            while(currentRandom == numOff) {
                currentRandom = Math.round(Math.random()*numOfQuestion);
                                                //создаем номер вопроса, не равный
                                                //предыдущему номеру
            }

            currentXML=externalXML.quest[currentRandom]; //текущий вопрос в виде XML
            var tf:TextField = new TextField;
            tf.text = currentXML.@text.toString();
            tf.setTextFormat(textF);
            tf.width = 400;
            tf.height = 40;             
            tf.x = 20;
            tf.y = 70;              
            tf.wordWrap = true;
            addChild(tf);

            var numMassiv:Array = [];
            for (var i=0; i<currentXML.answer.length(); i++) {
                numMassiv[i] = i
            }               
            var answerMassiv:Array = [];
            var answerNum = numMassiv.length;
            for (var k=0; k<answerNum; k++) {
                var kk = Math.round(Math.random()*(numMassiv.length-1));
                answerMassiv[k]=new AnswerBut(currentXML.answer[numMassiv[kk]]);
                if (numMassiv[kk] == 0) answerMassiv[k].correct = true;
                answerMassiv[k].num = currentRandom;
                trace(currentRandom);
                numMassiv.splice(kk,1);
                answerMassiv[k].x=30;
                answerMassiv[k].y=k*20+120;
                addChild(answerMassiv[k]);
                answerMassiv[k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            }

    }

    function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var prev = new Number(e.target.num);

        //удаляем всех потомков класса          
        if (this.numChildren>1) {
            while (this.numChildren > 1) {
                this.removeChildAt(1);
            }
        }                   
        asking(prev);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: А в какой строке выпадает ошибка?

Comment: @ShockWave, в разделе "Вывод", там не указана строка. Строка обычно указывается в "Ошибки и компиляции".

Comment: А что за среда разработки? Во FlashDevelop, закладка Locals, можно посмотреть состояние полей и переменных.